# Best 'private' spots for stargazing on Mountain Teide, Tenerife

Tags: mountains, tenerife, star-gazing

I'm planning travel to Tenerife in the end of May and one of the things which I like to do is do enjoy in a beautiful star scenery. I did some investigation and I concluded the best place is somewhere around the mountain Teide which is far away from resorts and therefore lights. I'll rent a car so getting there is not a problem at all. The real question is, are there any good places around or on Mountain Teide where I can drive on the night and just enjoy the stars (without telescope or similar, I'm pretty sure that I'll be shocked with my eyes also because I never saw too many stars, damn light polluting).

So I'm looking for good spotting places with following:

1. If possible private spots, because I'm planning to go there with my girlfriend and want to have as much romantic mood as I can
2. Reachable by car, because I don't find it relaxing walking too much outside of the road in the middle of the night in the middle of the mountain :) I can do some walking, but not too much :)

I saw that there are many stargazing tours, but I'm looking something private for couples where we can just sit somewhere and enjoy the stars without dinner or similar experience which are offered.

Any other advice is welcome and if you have any suggestions just let me know. If you can reference spots on google maps or similar, that would be perfect :)

Comment: You might be interested to know that neighbouring La Palma is an official [UNESCO Starlight Preserve](http://astrolapalma.com/en/Starlight-Reserve-in-La-Palma).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You Might Have to Hike

After reading up on hiking and stargazing on Mount Teide I'm starting to get the feeling that private spots, far away from organised groups and other similar tourists, will require you to hike one of the many trails available. Hence your second condition (reachability by car) won't be fully satisfied.

Moreover I'm under the impression that no stargazing fanatic or photographer will ever tell you the secret locations where they usually hang out. Indeed I found many stunning pictures on the web, but little or no mention to where they were shot.

Therefore, for the purpose of this answer I will assume that you are indeed willing to hike a little. For more information I advise you to read [this guide for hiking in Tenerife](http://www.fell-walker.co.uk/page66.htm). It seems to be the most complete one out there.

#### Mirador and Hike

In my opinion your best bet is to drive up to the mirador a couple hours before sunset, park and walk around there to search for a private spot. If you want more freedom of  movement you can consider getting the permit which allows you to hike all the way to the summit. Quoting from the aforementioned website:

> #### Obtaining your summit permit
>
> Summit permits (free) are obtainable in person from :
>
> ```
>    Office P. N. de Teide, 
>    Calle Emillio Calzadilla 5 
>    38002 Santa Cruz de Tenerife 
>    Phone 922 29 01 29 or 922 29 01 83 
>    Opening hours (Monday to Friday except public holidays) 9 am to 2 pm
> ```

My assumption is that the organised tours won't be hiking all the way up, giving you a higher chance of being left alone while stargazing. You might even have to repeat this operation a couple times to find the ideal location.

#### Plan Ahead

Consider that free camping is illegal on the national and natural park. Therefore I would avoid pitching a tent to wait for the stars.

Don't forget to bring a few head lamps and warm waterproof clothes. The mountain is high and the temperature has a tendency of dropping dramatically overnight. Moreover keep in mind that the altitude of the mountain calls for a careful slow ascent, to allow you to get used to the thin rarefied air.

Comment: Thank you for your detail answer. Let's wait little time more for more possible answers, but you are on the good way for the bounty win :) Question. Do I need to worry about safety during the night, around Mountain Teide? Any personal experience?

Comment: Sorry I have no personal experience...yet. Researching for this answer made me *very* curious. :) In terms of safety I would expect park rangers to be out and about checking for campers, and considering the number of organised tours I would assume that safety shouldn't be too much of an issue. Nevertheless exercise some precautions. ;)

Comment: Excuse me, @JoErNano, but is "mirador" a mistake for "parador" – as in the hotel at the south-western end of Las Cañadas? A mirador is a viewpoint. The road across Las Cañadas might itself be an option in the middle of the night; I don't know for sure, but I should be surprised if any cars are traversing it at 03:00.

Comment: @DavidPugh The Parador is the hotel/restaurant. [According to the linked guide, there are also two miradors](http://www.fell-walker.co.uk/page66.htm) one of which is next to a car park. My suggestion is to drive up there, park and walk.

Comment: Sorry. Now I think I kow what you mean by at least one mirador, the one with a car park. Due west of the parador, in among the weird volcanic spires, yes? Then I think anyone who has walked past/through those spires is going to have the night desert to zirself.